How to get Fetch API promise to resolve as soon as possible?
TL;DR: I expected the fetch API to resolve once the full HTTP response header was sent, but it is taking 8000ms for some reason.
I have a server using Express to respond to HTTP requests. It doesn't give a single response, but rather it makes multiple write calls over time to give status updates. In the browser, the HTTP request is made using the fetch API. The response body is iterated over asynchronously.
All of this works fine except for one issue. The time it takes to await the response from the fetch call is about 8 seconds. I know that the first chunk sent by the server does not take 8 seconds. I have even compared to XHR, which is taking less than 50ms for the progress event to fire. Is there anything I can do to make the initial fetch promise resolve sooner?
Server Code
app.post("/bulk-update", (req, res) => {
  buildTask(req.body, 5, (status) => {
    const completed = status.success + status.error;
    const remaining = status.total - completed;

    if (remaining === 0) {
      res.write(`${JSON.stringify(status)}\n`);
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    if (completed % 10 === 0) {
      res.write(`${JSON.stringify(status)}\n`);
    }
  });
});

Browser Code

let jobStartTime = Date.now();
const response = await fetch(`/bulk-update`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body,
});
console.log("end request", Date.now() - jobStartTime); // <-- this is logging 8000ms

const stream = response.body.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream());

let buffer = "";
for await (const chunk of stream) {
  buffer += chunk;

  const lines = buffer.split("\n");
  buffer = lines.at(-1);
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
    const line = lines[i];
    const status = JSON.parse(line);
    updateProgress(status);
  }

  if (buffer.trim().length > 0) {
    const status = JSON.parse(buffer);
    updateProgress(status);
  }
}


fetch does not have an equivalent to XMLHttpRequest's progress event - fetch doesn't mean XMLHttpRequest is uncool to use, it still has it's place and is not going away - edit: you can use "streams" on request bodies in all browsers except firefox for now -

The point of this question is not about the proper implementation of server events. It's specifically about the fetch API, and getting a stream as soon as possible. I thought should resolve once the header was parsed by the browser. If I'm mistaken about that, then I would accept a simple answer that fetch cannot do this, and XMLHttpRequest is more suitable for my task.

Are you sure the TTFB is under 8 seconds? It’s possible the response is being buffered by the server or some intermediary…

@deceze Yes, because I tested with XMLHttpRequest and it did not have a 8 second TTFB. I did some experimentation and managed to resolve the issue. It seems that this issue was specific to Firefox. I tested on Chrome and it resolved quickly with my original code.

"this issue was specific to Firefox" This would have been useful to mention in the post itself.

I was able to get the fetch to resolve sooner by setting the Content-Type header to text/event-stream in the response from the server. It seems that if the fetch does not see this header, it takes longer to resolve.
app.post("/bulk-update", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream'); // <-- this is the line the fixed it
  res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive'); // Not needed for quick fetch, just is accurate

  buildTask(req.body, 5, (status) => {
    const completed = status.success + status.error;
    const remaining = status.total - completed;

    if (remaining === 0) {
      res.write(`${JSON.stringify(status)}\n`);
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    if (completed % 10 === 0) {
      res.write(`${JSON.stringify(status)}\n`);
    }
  });
});

I didn't see anything in the Fetch Standard about this. I also tested on Chrome and fetch resolved quickly without needing the header. As far as I can tell, this is an implementation detail specifically with Firefox.

While res.write(data) is sent as Transfer-Encoding: chunked, seems Firefox is still buffering the data, but only if no Content-Type header is set.
Considering you are sending lines of JSON, using application/jsonl or application/jsonlines as Content-Type seems appropriate.
